# Laravel 5.1 and illuminate html FORM Multiple select

Tags: php, laravel-5.1, laravel-form

I have a problem with multiple select in laravel using illuminate html, I want to pre-select items, it works when I put them manuelly with an array like this :

```
{!! Form::select('tags_list[]', $tags, [2, 3], ['class' => 'form-control', 'multiple' => true]) !!}
```

But when I use a model to put the list, like this :

```
{!! Form::select('tags_list[]', $tags, $post->tags_list, ['class' => 'form-control', 'multiple' => true]) !!}
```

**It doesn't work** and I checked the list is returned correctly, here is the result of :

```
dd($post->tags_list);

Collection {#273 ▼
  #items: array:2 [▼
    0 => 1
    1 => 2
  ]
}
```

And here is the method that return the tags_list

```
public function getTagsListAttribute()
    {
        return $this->tags->lists('id');
    }
```

I am new in Laravel framework, can anyone help me with this issue, thanks in advance

Comment: Call `$post->tags_list->get()` to get the array off of the colleciton.

Comment: @Ohgodwhy Thanks for your quick reply, I already get the list in my Model, I will put the code in my post, please take a look

Answer (score 0):

```
      <div class="form-group">
                {!! Form::labelControl('user_type','User Type'),['class'=>'control-label col-md-2'], TRUE )  !!}

                <div class="col-md-3">
                    {!! Form::select('user_type[]', $selected_users, null, ['id'=>'user_type','multiple'=>'multiple','multiselect'=>'multiselect','class'=>'form-control']) !!}
                </div>

      </div>



       <script>
                    $(document).ready(function () {
                        $("#user_type").multiselect();
                   });
       </script>
```

[image]

> Things to remember:

- user_type is the array that contains the type of users like : Teacher , Tutor , Admin etc...
- This name should be same as the table in your db(in my case table name is user_type)
- $selected_users is the array that contains the id of the users that need to be pre selected.